# add style to embedded image

Tags: php, phpmailer

I send an embedded image in an email.  I use:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("../public/img/swb.jpg", "swb-image");
```

When I look at the source of the email I find the following:

```
<img border=0 width=915 height=187 style='width:9.5333in;height:1.95in' id="Picture_x0020_3" src="cid:swb-image" alt="cid:swb-image">
```

Is there a way to add:  `style="border-radius: 15px;`

If it's not possible to add style to embedded image is it possible to round the corners of the image in php?

my email function looks like:

```
function mailerExpressBlueHost(array $mailInputs){


          require_once '../includes/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

          $mail = new PHPMailer();
          $mail->IsMail();          
          $mail->SetFrom('skipper@sailwbob.com');
          $mail->IsHTML(true);
          $mail->addAddress($mailInputs['addAddress']);

          $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("../public/img/swb.jpg", "swb-image"); 

          $body = $mailInputs['body'] ;
          $mail->isHTML(true);
          $mail->Subject = $mailInputs['subject'] ;
          $mail->Body    = $body;

         if(!$mail->send()) {
         return 'Message could not be sent.' . 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

          } else {
         return 'Message has been sent';
          }

          $mail->ClearAddresses();

}
```

Comment: What is creating the `$mail` object that `AddEmbeddedImage` is part of?

Comment: function mailerExpressBlueHost(array $mailInputs){.....

Comment: Is the styling you showed found in the `AddEmbeddedImage` method? The function you mention doesn't appear to be a standard/normal thing that is generally available.

Comment: AddEmbeddedImage is part of php.  I don't see any documentation about style

Comment: It's part of PHPMailer not PHP itself but I don't see any styling being done in PHPMailer so it sounds like it might your mail client that is doing the styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but PHPMailer doesn't have anything to do with it - it's entirely down to what you put in your message body, and it's subject to the many differences in email client apps. Also, you're mixing pixels and inch units for dimensions, and being inconsistent about quoting attributes. Try this:

```
<img border="0" width="915" height="187" style="width:915px;height:187px;border-radius: 15px;" id="Picture_x0020_3" src="cid:swb-image" alt="swb-image">
```

It may be that the border radius property is not supported on images, in which case you may be able to do it by wrapping it in a div that applies it instead:

```
<div style="border-radius: 15px;">
    <img border="0" width="915" height="187" style="width:915px;height:187px;" id="Picture_x0020_3" src="cid:swb-image" alt="swb-image">
</div>
```

As far as PHPMailer goes, the only thing that matters is that the `cid` value you use in your message body is the same as the `cid` param you pass into `addEmbeddedImage`.